# How to backup docroot using tar

Tags: linux, backup, tar

I have a question about performing routing backups on our webserver.   Currently we are running Apache and we want to backup our doc root.  I have a shell script that runs nightly and the command I use is: sudo tar cvzf filename targetFilename.

My question is is it safe to run a tar cvzf command on a doc root if files are being read, written, created?  Is there a better way to do this?  Is it a good idea to shut down Apache while creating the tar file?

I've done some research and I couldn't find a straight forward answer.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

**it's safe**

System Deny A and B are writing file same the time because file locked.

tar backup is reading the files and create new file . it's ok.but shutdown web server is  the best way to backup files .